# Render or not to render? Building a tile server

Tags: render, openstreetmap, mapnik

So here I come with my first Stackoverflow question:)

It's been already some days spent on building my own tile server. As many others I followed instructions written [on switch2osm site](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/) and unfortunately got no luck.

When I run command `renderd -f -c /etc/renderd.conf` it seems to start to prepare itself but then it stops without any error and nothing happens. The last message it shows is: `renderd[4226] <Debug>: Using web mercator projection settings` and ... silence!

Please help me, I'm going crazy and can't sleep:)

Here is my data:

**OS**: Mac OS 10.9.4
**Python**: 2.7.5
**Mapnik**: 3.0.1-pre
**Server version**: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix)

Render messages:

```
renderd[4226] <Info>: Rendering daemon started
renderd[4226] <Error>: Initiating reqyest_queue
renderd[4226] <Info>: Parsing section renderd
renderd[4226] <Info>: Parsing render section 0
renderd[4226] <Info>: Parsing section renderd01
renderd[4226] <Info>: Parsing render section 1
renderd[4226] <Info>: Parsing section renderd02
renderd[4226] <Info>: Parsing render section 2
renderd[4226] <Info>: Parsing section mapnik
renderd[4226] <Info>: Parsing section default
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd: unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd: num_threads=4
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd: num_slaves=8
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd: tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd: stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
renderd[4226] <Info>: config mapnik:  plugins_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input
renderd[4226] <Info>: config mapnik:  font_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts
renderd[4226] <Info>: config mapnik:  font_dir_recurse=1
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd(0): Active
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd(0): unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd(0): num_threads=4
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd(0): tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd(0): stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd(1): unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd(1): num_threads=4
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd(1): tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd(1): stats_file=(null)
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd(2): unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd(2): num_threads=4
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd(2): tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[4226] <Info>: config renderd(2): stats_file=(null)
renderd[4226] <Info>: config map 0:   name(default) file(/Users/Alenka/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml) uri(/osm_tiles/) htcp() host(localhost)
renderd[4226] <Info>: Initialising unix server socket on /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[4226] <Debug>: Created server socket 3
renderd[4226] <Info>: Renderd is using mapnik version 3.0.0
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSerif.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSerifCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSerifCondensed-Italic.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts/unifont-7.0.05.ttf
Running in foreground mode...
Jul 30 18:46:39 Alenkas-iMac.local renderd[4226] <Debug>: Starting stats thread
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[4226] <Info>: Initialising unix client socket on /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[4226] <Info>: Initialising unix client socket on /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[4226] <Info>: Initialising unix client socket on /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[4226] <Info>: Loading parameterization function for
renderd[4226] <Info>: Loading parameterization function for
renderd[4226] <Info>: Loading parameterization function for
renderd[4226] <Info>: Loading parameterization function for
renderd[4226] <Info>: Initialising unix client socket on /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[4226] <Info>: Initialising unix client socket on /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[4226] <Info>: Initialising unix client socket on /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[4226] <Info>: Initialising unix client socket on /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[4226] <Info>: Initialising unix client socket on /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[4226] <Info>: socket /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock initialised to fd 4
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 7, number 1
renderd[4226] <Info>: socket /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock initialised to fd 8
renderd[4226] <Info>: socket /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock initialised to fd 9
renderd[4226] <Info>: socket /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock initialised to fd 11
renderd[4226] <Info>: socket /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock initialised to fd 13
renderd[4226] <Info>: socket /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock initialised to fd 14
renderd[4226] <Info>: socket /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock initialised to fd 15
renderd[4226] <Info>: socket /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock initialised to fd 17
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 19, number 2
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 20, number 3
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 21, number 4
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 22, number 5
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 23, number 6
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 24, number 7
renderd[4226] <Debug>: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 25, number 8
renderd[4226] <Debug>: Using web mercator projection settings
renderd[4226] <Debug>: Using web mercator projection settings
renderd[4226] <Debug>: Using web mercator projection settings
renderd[4226] <Debug>: Using web mercator projection settings
```

Logs from /var/log/apache2/error_log:

```
[error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/osm_tiles/0
[error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/osm_tiles/14
[notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[notice] Digest: done
[notice] Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y configured -- resuming normal operations
[notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[notice] Digest: done
[notice] Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y configured -- resuming normal operations
```

/etc/renderd.conf:

```
[renderd]
;socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
num_threads=4
tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats

[renderd01]
;iphostname=::1
;ipport=7654
;num_threads=4
;tile_dir=rados://tiles/etc/ceph/ceph.conf
;stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats

[renderd02]
;iphostname=::1
;ipport=7654
;num_threads=8
;tile_dir=memcached://
;stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats

[mapnik]
plugins_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input
font_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts
font_dir_recurse=1

[default]
URI=/osm_tiles/
TILEDIR=/var/lib/mod_tile
XML=/Users/Alenka/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml
HOST=localhost
TILESIZE=256
;HTCPHOST=proxy.openstreetmap.org
;MINZOOM=0
;MAXZOOM=18
;TYPE=png image/png
;DESCRIPTION=This is a description of the tile layer used in the tile json request
;ATTRIBUTION=&copy;<a href=\"http://www.openstreetmap.org/\">OpenStreetMap</a> and <a href=\"http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Contributors\">contributors</a>, <a href=\"http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/\">ODbL</a>
;SERVER_ALIAS=http://localhost/
;CORS=*
;ASPECTX=1
;ASPECTY=1
;SCALE=1.0
```

mod_tile.conf:

```
LoadModule tile_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_tile.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /osm_tiles/

    LoadTileConfigFile /etc/renderd.conf
    ModTileRenderdSocketName /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
    # Timeout before giving up for a tile to be rendered
    ModTileRequestTimeout 0
    # Timeout before giving up for a tile to be rendered that is otherwise missing
    ModTileMissingRequestTimeout 30

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I've checked all the paths, I've googled everything. I'm not denying I might've missed smth, but I think when I look at the screen I understand nothing, my head is a complete mess right now.

P.s. btw I'm not sure if mod_tile and renderd are installed correctly as while I was doing `make` process I got some errors in the end (the same was for `sudo make install` and `sudo make imstall-mod_tile`):

```
Making all in iniparser3.0b
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
apxs -c   -I./includes    -lcurl ./src/mod_tile.c  ./src/sys_utils.c ./src/store.c ./src/store_file.c ./src/store_file_utils.c ./src/store_memcached.c ./src/store_rados.c ./src/store_ro_http_proxy.c ./src/store_ro_composite.c ./src/store_null.c
/usr/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=compile /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.9.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -I./includes  -c -o ./src/mod_tile.lo ./src/mod_tile.c && touch ./src/mod_tile.slo
./src/mod_tile.c:325:41: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_os_thread_t'
      (aka 'struct _opaque_pthread_t *') [-Wformat]
            tile_layer, lifecycle_pool, os_thread);
                                        ^~~~~~~~~
./src/mod_tile.c:338:164: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_os_thread_t'
      (aka 'struct _opaque_pthread_t *') [-Wformat]
  ...No storage backends for this lifecycle %pp, creating it in thread %li", lifecycle_pool, os_thread);
                                                                       ~~~                   ^~~~~~~~~
./src/mod_tile.c:346:160: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_os_thread_t'
      (aka 'struct _opaque_pthread_t *') [-Wformat]
  ...Found backends (%pp) for this lifecycle %pp in thread %li", stores, lifecycle_pool, os_thread);
                                                           ~~~                           ^~~~~~~~~
./src/mod_tile.c:354:33: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_os_thread_t'
      (aka 'struct _opaque_pthread_t *') [-Wformat]
                lifecycle_pool, os_thread, tile_layer);
                                ^~~~~~~~~
./src/mod_tile.c:358:45: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_os_thread_t'
      (aka 'struct _opaque_pthread_t *') [-Wformat]
                lifecycle_pool, tile_layer, os_thread);
                                            ^~~~~~~~~
./src/mod_tile.c:375:75: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'off_t' (aka 'long long')
      [-Wformat]
                      cmd->xmlname, cmd->x, cmd->y, cmd->z, rdata->store, stat.size, stat.expired, stat.mtime);
                                                                          ^~~~~~~~~
./src/mod_tile.c:505:22: warning: format specifies type 'long long' but the argument has type 'long' [-Wformat]
                     maxAge));
                     ^~~~~~
./src/mod_tile.c:756:19: error: no member named 's6_addr32' in 'struct in6_addr'
    hashkey = (ip.s6_addr32[0] ^ ip.s6_addr32[1] ^ ip.s6_addr32[2] ^ ip.s6_addr32[3]) % DELAY_HASHTABLE_SIZE;
               ~~ ^
./src/mod_tile.c:756:37: error: no member named 's6_addr32' in 'struct in6_addr'
    hashkey = (ip.s6_addr32[0] ^ ip.s6_addr32[1] ^ ip.s6_addr32[2] ^ ip.s6_addr32[3]) % DELAY_HASHTABLE_SIZE;
                                 ~~ ^
./src/mod_tile.c:756:55: error: no member named 's6_addr32' in 'struct in6_addr'
    hashkey = (ip.s6_addr32[0] ^ ip.s6_addr32[1] ^ ip.s6_addr32[2] ^ ip.s6_addr32[3]) % DELAY_HASHTABLE_SIZE;
                                                   ~~ ^
./src/mod_tile.c:756:73: error: no member named 's6_addr32' in 'struct in6_addr'
    hashkey = (ip.s6_addr32[0] ^ ip.s6_addr32[1] ^ ip.s6_addr32[2] ^ ip.s6_addr32[3]) % DELAY_HASHTABLE_SIZE;
                                                                     ~~ ^
./src/mod_tile.c:1084:21: warning: format specifies type 'long long' but the argument has type 'long' [-Wformat]
                    maxAge));
                    ^~~~~~
./src/mod_tile.c:1129:39: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
    ap_rprintf(r, "NoResp200: %li\n", local_stats.noResp200);
                              ~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                              %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1130:39: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
    ap_rprintf(r, "NoResp304: %li\n", local_stats.noResp304);
                              ~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                              %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1131:39: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
    ap_rprintf(r, "NoResp404: %li\n", local_stats.noResp404);
                              ~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                              %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1132:39: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
    ap_rprintf(r, "NoResp503: %li\n", local_stats.noResp503);
                              ~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                              %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1133:39: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
    ap_rprintf(r, "NoResp5XX: %li\n", local_stats.noResp5XX);
                              ~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                              %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1134:41: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
    ap_rprintf(r, "NoRespOther: %li\n", local_stats.noRespOther);
                                ~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1135:42: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
    ap_rprintf(r, "NoFreshCache: %li\n", local_stats.noFreshCache);
                                 ~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                 %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1136:40: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
    ap_rprintf(r, "NoOldCache: %li\n", local_stats.noOldCache);
                               ~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                               %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1137:44: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
    ap_rprintf(r, "NoVeryOldCache: %li\n", local_stats.noVeryOldCache);
                                   ~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                   %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1138:43: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
    ap_rprintf(r, "NoFreshRender: %li\n", local_stats.noFreshRender);
                                  ~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                  %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1139:41: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
    ap_rprintf(r, "NoOldRender: %li\n", local_stats.noOldRender);
                                ~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1140:45: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
    ap_rprintf(r, "NoVeryOldRender: %li\n", local_stats.noVeryOldRender);
                                    ~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                    %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1142:51: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
        ap_rprintf(r, "NoRespZoom%02i: %li\n", i, local_stats.noRespZoom[i]);
                                       ~~~        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                       %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1144:47: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
    ap_rprintf(r, "NoTileBufferReads: %li\n", local_stats.noTotalBufferRetrieval);
                                      ~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                      %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1145:53: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
    ap_rprintf(r, "DurationTileBufferReads: %li\n", local_stats.totalBufferRetrievalTime);
                                            ~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                            %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1147:61: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
        ap_rprintf(r, "NoTileBufferReadZoom%02i: %li\n", i, local_stats.noZoomBufferRetrieval[i]);
                                                 ~~~        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                 %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1148:67: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
        ap_rprintf(r, "DurationTileBufferReadZoom%02i: %li\n", i, local_stats.zoomBufferRetrievalTime[i]);
                                                       ~~~        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                       %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1153:70: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
        ap_rprintf(r,"NoRes200Layer%s: %li\n", tile_config->baseuri, local_stats.noResp200Layer[i]);
                                       ~~~                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                       %llu
./src/mod_tile.c:1154:70: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'apr_uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wformat]
        ap_rprintf(r,"NoRes404Layer%s: %li\n", tile_config->baseuri, local_stats.noResp404Layer[i]);
                                       ~~~                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                       %llu
27 warnings and 4 errors generated.
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

Comment: Your compiler complained about errors in mod_tile.c. With errors the binary can't get created. Hence you won't have a working mod_tile installation.

Comment: Does this mean that I'm never gonna have this working or there is smth that can be done about it?

Comment: It means you have a different problem and should ask a new question about compiling mod_tile :) I don't know the reason for this error.

Comment: I've reinstalled mod_tile and this time I got only some warnings without any errors (I think it's been installed...), but rendering still not working.

Answer (score 1):

`renderd[4226] <Debug>: Using web mercator projection settings` means everything is OK. The configuration of mapnik and mod_tile is correct. It seems that your Apache doesn't work well.

Firstly, make sure your Apache is working well. You need to visit `localhost:80` to verify if the Apache works well. If Apache does not work, you need to check the firewall if the port 80 is open. On CentOS, you can use `netstat -ntlp` to check if the port 80 is listening. After that, you can visit the website `localhost:80` again. If Apache works well, you will see apache default page.

If renderd still not working, you need to check the logs from Apache such as `/var/log/apache2/error_log`. This time the problem probably come from `socket connect failed for: /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock with reason: Permission denied`, this problem comes from SELinux, you can just turn it off by `setenforce 0`.

You can solve these problems by analysing the logs from Apache after Apache working well.