# Compiling mod_tile

Tags: c, rendering, tile

I wanted to build my own tile server as written on switch2osm site. In short: render is not happening (more details you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729036/render-or-not-to-render-building-a-tile-server)).

Seems that mod_tile is not installed correctly. First it gave some errors during installation and in the end error message was:

```
27 warnings and 4 errors generated.
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

I removed this source (original from openstreet) and downloaded new one from [here](https://github.com/springmeyer/mod_tile). This time installation went without error, only some warnings. But rendering is still not happening (it's stuck on `<Debug>: Using web mercator projection settings` and doesn't move on).

Data about my system goes here:
**OS**: Mac OS 10.9.4 
**Python**: 2.7.5
**Mapnik**: 3.0.1-pre
**Server version**: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix)

Installation logs are [here](https://gist.github.com/narcissic/69ac6a451ce3cd7da055).